# Summation in Haskell - functional programing

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I'm having trouble writing a simple function in Haskell... It is meant to calculate the sum of numbers from 1 to n. I'm not allowed to use if statements because my teacher want us to focus on functional programing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
summation :: Integer -> Integer
summation n
  | n > 1 = n + summation(n-1)
  | n == 1 = 1
```

This is the output from GHCi:

```
clase4.hs:13:28: error:
    Variable not in scope: (?) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Line 13 is:

```
     | n > 1 = n + summation(n-1)
```

I've commented everything else in the file and I still get that error. I cannot see '?' anywhere. These are the screen captures:

[image: File]

[image: GHCi output]

Comment: `?` isn't in that code. Can you please create a [mcve]?

Comment: By the way, there's a [more efficient algorithm for that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#Partial_sums).

Comment: thats all i've written, '?' does not appear anywhere in the file

Comment: It [compiles fine for me](https://ideone.com/1aAz8B), so I'm not sure what's causing that error. Could you try to isolate the problem some more until the problem goes away? Then post the code which produces the error.

Comment: you'll face `Non-exhaustive patterns` exception for values `< 1`

Comment: The error message references line 13; you've only shown 4 lines of code. What else is in the file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your source file `clase4.hs`, the character you *think* is a standard ASCII minus sign in the expression `n-1` isn't.  Instead, you've probably used some other unicode character, like an "en dash" or something that only *looks* like a minus sign (perhaps because you've edited the file in something weird like Microsoft Word or copied and pasted the code from some source that was messing with the characters).

Haskell is printing the invalid character as a "?" because, as far as it can tell, your output terminal doesn't support the encoding necessary to display the bad character.  (This is a common problem when running Haskell in a Windows environment, though it might happen on other platforms if things were set up strangely.)

Open the source file with a proper text editor, highlight the "minus sign" and re-type it on your keyboard.  On a Spanish keyboard, this should be the key to the left of the bottom-right shift key; on a US keyboard, it's to the right of the zero key.

If that fails, try copying and pasting your own program above from Stack Overflow into a brand new text file and compile that -- copying and pasting from your question is working fine for the rest of us.

Comment: That was it!!! changing the character worked, i still don't know how i tipped it and why when i paste the code here it became a minus sign, but i don't think that is very important. thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that there are two problems here:

1. your recursive call calls `sumatoria` whereas your function is `summation`;
2. you check for `n > 1` and `n == 1` which is rather unsafe.

We can resolve the problems by subsituting `sumatoria` by `summation`, and make the guards more safe:

```
summation :: Integer -> Integer
summation n
  | n >= 1 = n + summation (n-1)
  | otherwise = 0
```

Now it should work. We use `otherwise = 0` such that if we enter `0` or a negative number, we obtain `0`.

Nevertheless we can still improve this function. First of all, we should not restrict ourselves to only `Integer`s. We can use any kind of `Num`eric type `a` that is `Ord`erable. So we can rewrite it to:

```
summation :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a
summation n
  | n > 1 = n + summation (n-1)
  | otherwise = 0
```

And furthermore the sum of `1..n` or `0..n` can be calculated by using:

```
n
---
\         n * (n+1)
/    i  = ---------
---           2
i=1
```

So we can write it as:

```
summation :: Integral a => a -> a
summation n = div (n * (n+1)) 2
```

The `div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a` requires `a` to be `Integral`. In case the multiplication, increment, and division are all *O(1)* operations, this is an *O(1)* function now.

Finally note that besides using recursion, you can also use functions like `sum`. In that case you could have used:

```
summation :: (Enum a, Num a) => a -> a
summation n = sum [1..n]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! the original file was in spanish so it read sumatoria everywhere, i've translated it to summation for posting it here and forgot to change that one. I like your approach, but i still want to understand why mine did no work.

Comment: @SantiagoAguilar: somewhere your source code contains a question mark `?` between two variables. But we can not see that.

Comment: i don't see '?' anywhere. I've uploaded pictures of the file and output. thank you!!